# Problem reading and augmenting images in tf.data API using CSV / pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to (pre)process and augment my data and target variables when reading in the data each epoch/batch using the tf.data API. My unprocessed data is a CSV/pandas DataFrame with the format
`index, img_id, c1, ..., c5` where img_id contains the path to an image while `c1,...,c5` are run length encodings of different defects in the image, both are strings. To increase the amount of data I want to augment (e.g. flip) the images (and therefore the masks of defects aswell) with a certain probability for each image when reading it each batch/epoch. I want to read each image from my drive to save memory and because this seems to still yield good performance within the API (due to prefetching etc).

I'm familiar doing this using pytorchs DataLoader API (using version `1.8.1+cu111`), but as this is for a course where I have to use tensorflow (using version `2.4.1`), I read up on the tf.data API and came to the conclusion that I should do this augmentation and reading of the image using the `map` function. However, even reading the images throws different errors. The following is a mix of the code I've tried to use, most lines for reading the images are commented out with an extra comment in the line above with the error message it will produce.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
test = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset("data/mini_formatted.csv", batch_size=4)

def map_fn(df_):    
    img_path = df_["img_id"]
    masks = restore_masks(df_) # get maps from RLE with same shape as images
    
    imgs = []
    # has to be declared before loop with correct shape, used for reading imgs later
    img = np.empty(shape=(256,1600,1), dtype=np.float32)
    
    # produces TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'Tensor' to 'str' for 'filename'
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
    for i in img_path:
        # produces TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'Tensor' to 'str' for 'filename'
        #img = cv2.imread(i, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        
        # produces AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
        #img = cv2.imread(str(i), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        
        # produces ValueError: 'img' has shape (256, 1600, 1) before the loop, but shape <unknown> after one iteration. Use tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options to set shape invariants.
        #img_file = tf.io.read_file(i)
        #img = tf.io.decode_image(img_file, dtype=tf.float32, channels=1)
        #imgs.append(img)
        pass
    
    # since img_path is a list, this doesn't work either
    # ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for '{{node ReadFile}} = ReadFile[](args_6)' with input shapes: [4].
    img_file = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_image(img_file, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    
    ##########################################
    #
    #     DO AUGMENTING PER BATCH HERE
    #
    ##########################################
    
    # return augmented images and masks
    return imgs, class_masks

proc_ds = test.map(map_fn)
```

As you can see, reading the image throws different errors I do not quite unterstand, especially because reading the image as follows (i.e. with the exact same commands after getting the first batch from the dataset without applying the map function) works without problems.

```py
it = test.as_numpy_iterator()
x_proc = it.next()

img_files = [tf.io.read_file(i) for i in x_proc["img_id"]]
imgs = [img = tf.io.decode_image(img_file, dtype=tf.float32, channels=1) for img_file in img_files]
```

From my understanding, using the `map` function on a dataset should execute the code on each example once per epoch, but from the example given, it seems the function is executed once per batch, what I tried to work around. This doesn't explain to me, why the same code doesn't work inside the `map` function, while working fine outside it.

To help understand what I want to do, I've written a short Dataset/DataLoader in torch as an example of what my desired outputs are.

```py
import torch
import pandas as pd

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, mode="train", shuffle=True, augment=False, union=False,
                 greyscale=False, normalize=True):
        self.df = df
        self.length = len(df)
        self.mode = mode
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.augment = augment
        self.union = union
        self.greyscale = greyscale
        self.normalize = normalize
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx_):
        # gets called for a single item when added to batch -> one line of the dataframe
        # in the tf example, these are grouped in an OrderedDict with arrays of length (BATCH_SIZE) as values 
        df_ = self.df.loc[idx_]
        
        img = self._load_img(df_["img_id"])
        if self.union:
            masks = build_masks(df_["c1":"c_all"], union_only=True)
        else:
            masks = build_masks(df_["c1":"c_all"])
        
        # could also add augmentation here instead of in collate_ds
        if self.mode == "train":
            return {"img": img, "masks": masks}
        return {"img": img, "masks": None}
        
        
    def _load_img(self, img_path):
        
        if self.greyscale:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        else:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            
        if self.normalize:
            img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255.
        else:
            img = img.astype(np.float32)
            
        return img 
    
    def collate_ds(self, batch):
        # gets called with BATCH_SIZE examples that were processed using __getitem__
        imgs = [d["img"] for d in batch]
        masks = [d["masks"] for d in batch]
        
        if self.augment:
            # augmentation steps for each image
            pass
        
        imgs = torch.tensor(imgs, dtype=torch.float32)
        masks = torch.tensor(masks, dtype=torch.float32)
        
        res = (imgs, masks)
        return res

mini_df = pd.read_csv("data/mini_formatted.csv", index_col=0)
torch_ds = MyDataset(mini_df, mode="train", shuffle=True, augment=False, union=False,
                 greyscale=False, normalize=True)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(torch_ds, batch_size=8, shuffle=True,
                                        collate_fn=torch_ds.collate_ds)
batch = next(iter(dataloader))
print(batch[0].shape, batch[1].shape) 
# output: (torch.Size([8, 256, 1600, 3]), torch.Size([8, 256, 1600, 5]))
```

I still don't understand, why even reading the images inside the `map` function doesn't work (e.g. using cv2 -> neither using `imread(img_path) #TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'Tensor' to 'str' for 'filename'` nor `imread(str(i) #AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' -> image wasn't found`  works, while the `tf.io.*` functions work outside the function, but throw errors when the exact same code is executed inside it.

I would be very thankful for any help on what I'm misunderstanding/doing wrong using the `map` function with the tf.data API and how I could achieve the same results as the provided torch dataloader using the tf.data API.

Comment: Did you check this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv

Comment: Yes, that's one of the parts I looked at to learn about the tf.data API and came to my understanding of the `map` function. I didn't get it to work as a tf dataset, but instead am working with a data generator using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` which works fine.